# Query Enum column in sqlalchemy leads to LookupError

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I thought I was following the docs pretty closely setting up an ENUM field in a Postgres DB with sqlalchemy, but I'm clearly doing something (hopefully something simple) wrong.

My table has a type `contact_type`:

```
                                        List of data types
 Schema |     Name      | Internal name | Size |   Elements    |  Owner   | Access privileges | Description
--------+---------------+---------------+------+---------------+----------+-------------------+-------------
 public | contact_types | contact_types | 4    | unknown      +| postgres |                   |
        |               |               |      | incoming_text+|          |                   |
        |               |               |      | incoming_call+|          |                   |
        |               |               |      | outgoing_call |          |                   |
```

and in the table:

```
  Table "public.calls"
    Column    |           Type           |                     Modifiers
--------------+--------------------------+----------------------------------------------------
 contact_type | contact_types            |
```

In python I created a subclass of `enum` per [the docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.Enum):

```
import enum

class contact_types(enum.Enum):
    unknown: 1
    incoming_text: 2
    incoming_call: 3
    outgoing_call: 4
```

and passed it to the model:

```
class Call(db.Model):
    contact_type = db.Column(db.Enum(contact_types))
```

It all looked good. Inserts work and I can see the values when looking at the table, but SQLAlchemy's validation seems to be unhappy when querying. This leads to an error:

```
calls = Call.query.order_by(Call.time.desc()).limit(pagesize).offset(offset)
for c in calls:
    print(c)
```

> LookupError: "unknown" is not among the defined enum values

'unknown' is in the Enum. Am I missing a step somewhere to connect the query to the enum class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there should be `=` in `enum` definition, not `:`

```
class contact_types(enum.Enum):
    unknown = 1
    incoming_text = 2
    incoming_call = 3
    outgoing_call = 4
```

Comment: Oh jeez, too much javascript infecting the brain…well at least it's an easy fix. Thanks.